# Rails 6.0.3 controller test errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I've created a new RoR 6.0.3.4 app on Ruby 2.7.1.

The app contains several basic scaffold structures, built using

`$rails g scaffold <thisname> name:string`

`$rails db:migrate`

`$rails test` fails each controller test immediately & returns a "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) error".

The failing controller test clause is auto-generated:

```
test "should get index" do 
  get <thisname>s_url
  assert_response :success
```

This makes zero sense. Has anybody solved this behavior?

Comment: Can you share the detailed error message maybe?

Comment: There's not much to add:
````<path>/test/controllers/<scaffold_name>s_controller_test.rb:8:in `test': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (ArgumentError)````

Comment: Thanks. Also possible to share the line of code with the error? test/controllers/<scaffold_name>s_controller_test.rb:8

Comment: see above, in the original post.

Comment: I tried the exact same steps, create new rails app, generate scaffold and test. It works as expected. Whick makes me think that it might be related to some model name (as you have not mentioned any configuration changes). I am not sure but it might be helpful to see the code as is (without replacing the model name). Trying to eliminate the causes here.

Comment: That was my first thought as well. I deleted the scaffold, then created another with a different name and same structure. Same test result.